# IPTABLES doesn't drop packets on closed ports

Tags: networking, iptables

So I've tried creating rules on iptables that block all packets on ports other than 21,22,27015 but floods/packets are able to reach and load my network from ports like 50 or 60.
Here's my list of rules that I've added on iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       206.81.9.31          0.0.0.0/0   
    6  4487 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27017
 238K  179M DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27016
    3  2273 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:111
8157K 6129M ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            recent: UPDATE seconds: 120 hit_count: 1 name: FREESWITCH_BADGUY side: source mask: 255.255.255.255 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "FREESWITCH BAD: "
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 21,22,27015 recent: SET name: FREESWITCH_BADGUY side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
8157K 6129M ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7565K 5761M ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7565K 5761M ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7565K 5761M ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7565K 5761M ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    1    40 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            #conn src/32 > 40 reject-with tcp-reset
    1    44 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW limit: avg 60/sec burst 20
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            #conn src/32 > 80 reject-with tcp-reset
  591 28740 SYNPROXY   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp ctstate INVALID,UNTRACKED SYNPROXY sack-perm timestamp wscale 7 mss 1460
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            #conn src/32 > 111 reject-with tcp-reset
    0     0            tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 10 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
2526K 1941M DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27016
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth1   *      !1.2.3.4              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:!80
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:!27016
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       185.226.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0   
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:1:20
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:23:27014
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:27016:65535
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 1:20
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 23:27014
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 27016:65500
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27015
 169K  128M DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 27016:65500
1985K 1518M DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 23:27014
  133  102K DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpts:27016:65535
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpts:23:27014
   96 72094 RATE-LIMIT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27015 limit: avg 150/min burst 200

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 80 packets, 4404 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
75873   29M ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
75873   29M ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 1784  106K ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 1784  106K ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 1784  106K ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 1784  106K ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain RATE-LIMIT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
   96 72094 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 151/sec burst 20
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: up to 50/sec burst 20
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: up to 150/sec burst 20
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "IPTables-Rejected: "

Chain port-scanning (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x17/0x04 limit: avg 1/sec burst 2
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
    4  2295 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
   73  3728 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
    3  2315 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    5  3950 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
  442 68204 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
   50  5262 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   
 6166  632K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
4713K 3577M ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
4713K 3577M ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
   50  5262 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   
61382   27M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  983 53571 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
4713K 3577M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
   85 12288 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
   21  1755 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
   81  4784 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
    6  4558 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27015
 511K  363M ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27015
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 /* 'dapp_OpenSSH' */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       185.226.88.178       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       206.81.9.31          0.0.0.0/0   

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 





------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N RATE-LIMIT
-N port-scanning
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-logging-allow
-N ufw-logging-deny
-N ufw-not-local
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-forward
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-N ufw-user-forward
-N ufw-user-input
-N ufw-user-limit
-N ufw-user-limit-accept
-N ufw-user-logging-forward
-N ufw-user-logging-input
-N ufw-user-logging-output
-N ufw-user-output
-A INPUT -s 206.81.9.31/32 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 27017 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 27016 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 111 -j DROP
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m recent --update --seconds 120 --hitcount 1 --name FREESWITCH_BADGUY --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "FREESWITCH BAD: " --log-level 6
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,22,27015 -m recent --set --name FREESWITCH_BADGUY --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 40 --connlimit-mask 32 --connlimit-saddr -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 60/sec --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 80 --connlimit-mask 32 --connlimit-saddr -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID,UNTRACKED -j SYNPROXY --sack-perm --timestamp --wscale 7 --mss 1460
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 111 --connlimit-mask 32 --connlimit-saddr -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 27016 -j DROP
-A INPUT ! -s 1.2.3.4/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp -m udp ! --dport 80 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp -m udp ! --dport 27016 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 185.226.0.0/16 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1:20 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23:27014 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27016:65535 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 1:20 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 23:27014 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 27016:65500 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 27016:65500 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 23:27014 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 27016:65535 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 23:27014 -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j RATE-LIMIT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 27015 -m limit --limit 150/min --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A RATE-LIMIT -m limit --limit 151/sec --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT
-A RATE-LIMIT -j DROP
-A RATE-LIMIT -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 50/sec --hashlimit-burst 20 --hashlimit-name conn_rate_limit -j ACCEPT
-A RATE-LIMIT -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 150/sec --hashlimit-burst 20 --hashlimit-name conn_rate_limit -j ACCEPT
-A RATE-LIMIT -j DROP
-A RATE-LIMIT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Rejected: "
-A port-scanning -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK RST -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 2 -j RETURN
-A port-scanning -j DROP
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_OpenSSH\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Where is your list of rules? I prefer the output from `sudo iptables -xvnL` and if you do NAT, also `sudo -t nat -xvnL`. Floods of packets still traverse and burden the iptables rule set, even if they ultimately get DROPped.

Comment: I can't post the entire list of rules here as it's more than 4000 characters. I uploaded it here: https://easyupload.io/ljhjtq

Comment: ufw generated iptables rule sets are very hard to read and follow. There are redundant rules in your rule set. I;ll check again tomorrow, but it looks as though there is a path through without getting DROPped.

Comment: I'll check today and hopefully I'll be able to find it. If not I hope you can find the path so that I can remove that rule that allows the packets through

Comment: When were the packet counters last zeroed in your rules list? Were you under a DDOS (Distributed Denial Of Service Attack) at the time, and is that why there are so many packets for UDP port 27016? And is that why another earlier (in the rule list) UDP dport 27016 DROP rule seems to have been added at what must have been later (in time). Please edit your question adding what each of eth0 and eth1 are used for. Your rule set is very confusing, if it were me I would start from scratch and not use ufw at all. But please be aware, there is not much you can do against a heavy DDOS attack.

Comment: I launched a DDOS attack on my server to see if I can stop it, but unfortunately I only managed to stop it when it came on large packets while when I used spoofed ips I couldn't stop the attack. There are a lot of packets because I attacked that port although it was supposed to be closed but the attack still reached.

Comment: The UDP dport 27016 rules are working properly, and the packets are dropped by iptables.

Comment: The packets were dropped only after I rewrote the code, but it still doesn't get filtered.